# Hibernating made my computer unbootable

Tags: windows-7, boot, hibernate, mbr, disk-encryption

For some reason hibernation was not enabled on my Windows 7 install.
So I enabled it, and then put the machine into hibernation.

I use [*McAfee Safeboot*](http://www.mcafee.com/hk/products/data-protection/index.aspx) on the machine (for data encryption).

Upon trying to boot it never gets to the *mcafee safeboot* screen and thus to the windows screen.

Is it possible that the *safebbot mbr* has been overwritten?
Otherwise what could the issue be?

The machine is a [HP elitebook 840](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/elite-products/elitebook-840.html).

Comment: I would contact McAfee support, endpoint software is constantly being patched with updates due to issues (bugs) like this, they will be more help to you than we can be.

Comment: @Moab, It wouldn't really make sense this is a McAfee issue, would it?

Comment: It does to me...

Comment: @Moab, Hibernate is a windows feature, and would only be relevant after safeboot unlocked the drive. How could hibernating a machine interfere with safeboot?

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that when hibernating, while encryption is on, *hiberfil.sys* was created. When trying to reboot, the encrypted file is not accessible.

You might boot using alternative media, such as a Linux distro or WinPE on a USB stick or CD and then delete *hiberfil.sys*. Of course, any work you had open before hibernating will be lost.

Comment: How would this prevent the machine from entering the safeboot login screen? This is what should boot first, and then pass control to windows, right? I'm going to try booting from a linux rescue distro, just trying to understand what happened. I've used h ibernation with safeboot in the past with out issue on different machines.

Comment: This is based on an experience testing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (from USB) on a Windows PC that had hibernation enabled (but not encrypted). Ubuntu refused to mount the HD until *hiberfil.sys* was removed. See http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/ubuntu/accessing-hiberfil_sys.php.